# Using phonegap to develop iphone app on visual studio

Tags: iphone, cordova, visual-studio-2013, mobile-application, icenium

I am completely new to mobile app development and basically c#,.net developer.Recently i got a requirement to develop a iPhone application.Some experts suggested me to use icenium extension for visual studio and Phonegap. I want to know how to use/install phonegap for this and how does phonegap helps me to develop this application?what are the basic difference between icenium and phonegap as i know both helps to develop cross platform apps.

Answer (score 2):

Telerik AppBuilder (formerly known as Icenium) is a set of IDEs and cloud-based build tools that allow you to use PhoneGap/Cordova to build cross-platform apps. You should read up on it and use their free trial here: http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder

Comment: is there any separate setting required in visual studio to use phonegap or it comes with phonegap?

Comment: IMHO the easiest way to get up and running with developing PhoneGap/Cordova apps in Visual Studio is to use the VS extension for Telerik AppBuilder. You can however, do it yourself manually by following the instructions at phonegap.com - but you then need a Mac for iOS builds. Disclaimer: I'm a Product Manager for AppBuilder at Telerik!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Nomad](http://vsnomad.com/). (Visual studio extension which integrates Adobe Phonegap Build)

---

### Update:

From http://vsnomad.com/

> **Retiring Nomad**
>
> When we made Nomad free, we hoped the support load would be
>   manageable. However, we’ve found our users still expect a lot of
>   support for free tools. We don’t want to give our users false
>   expectations, so we think it’s better that they find another solution
>   with full support. For this reason, we will retire Nomad on September
>   1st this year.
>
> **Alternatives to Nomad**
>
> Nomad uses the open-source Cordova framework. This means you can move
>   Nomad projects to other vendors that use Cordova, including:
>
> [PhoneGap Build (Adobe)](https://build.phonegap.com/)
>       Instead of using PhoneGap Build via Nomad, you can interact with it directly using the PhoneGap Build command line.
>
> [Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Microsoft)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381.aspx)
>       A Visual Studio extension that adds PhoneGap support.
>
> [AppBuilder (Telerik)](http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder/visual-studio-extension)
>       A Visual Studio extension similar to Nomad.

Comment: Is Nomad still in active development? The blog hasn't been updated in nearly a year and the download link wouldn't work for me...

Comment: Nomad has been retired

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Preview)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381.aspx) from Microsoft.

Don't you just love their naming conventions...

I haven't had a chance to try it myself as it requires VS2013 and Windows 8.1, but it looks promising.

Comment: Windows 8.1 is required only for windows Phone development